# Kendo for jQuery: Load data to chart without k-rebind

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I'm working with chart from Kendo for jQuery (in AngularJS project) and am trying to fill the chart with relatively big amount of data (cca 10 000 items) loaded from backend. Currently my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="chart" kendo-chart="chart" k-options="model.chartOptions" k-rebind="model.chartOptions.series"></div>
```

What is happening here is that after the data are loaded from BE, they are copied once before chart rendering and once after that. This results into cca 30-second delay, 7 seconds are spent for first copying, 7 seconds for second and the rest for rendering.

[image]

I suppose I cannot do anything about the time in the middle (consumed by chart rendering), so I wonder if there is a way how to get rid of the copying. The only idea that came to my mind was about getting rid of the `k-rebind` - I read somewhere it refreshes the widget (and probably copies the data) everytime the underlying property changes - and replace it with

```
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
chart.refresh();
```

which should take new data and refresh the widget, but it has no effect.

So am I using the `k-rebind` wrong way? Or is there any way how to avoid it?

**UPDATE**

After days of searching I decided to use the jQuery way. My code now looks like this:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

```
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        seriesDefaults: {
            categoryField: "endTimestamp",
            field: "value",
            stack: false´,
            type: "line"
        },
        categoryAxis: {
            type: "date",
            baseUnit: "minutes",
            baseUnitStep: 15,
        },
        series: [
            {
            name: "First serie",
            data: [
                {
                    value: 150,
                    startTimestamp: new Date(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                    endTimestamp: new Date(2021, 8, 1, 0, 15, 0)
                },
                {
                    value: 162,
                    startTimestamp: new Date(2021, 8, 1, 0, 15, 0),
                    endTimestamp: new Date(2021, 8, 1, 0, 30, 0)
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
    });
```

Everything seems working fine. Now I need to add some data to the serie and to show them, like this:

```
chart.options.series[0].data.push({
    value: 110,
    startTimestamp: new Date(2021, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    endTimestamp: new Date(2021, 8, 1, 0, 15, 0)
});
chart.refresh();
```

Before `refresh` there are 3 items in `series[0].data`, after it there are 0 items and no data is shown in chart.

Note: I do not use `chart.redraw` as it does not wide the chart - it does not show the added values.

Interesting thing is that if I try the same thing on 'simple' data (just array of numbers), everything works fine, even the `chart.refresh()`.

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    seriesDefaults: {
        type: "line"
    },
    series: [
        {
        name: "First serie",
        data: [ 100, 200 ]
        }
    ]
});

chart.options.series[0].data.push(300);
chart.refresh();
```

Thanks in advance for any tip.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "after the data are loaded from BE, they are copied once before chart rendering and once after that". What is this copy event, and why/when is it happening? As for your alternative approach, you've bound the chart instance to a variable using `kendo-chart="chart"`, so you should be able to just use `$scope.chart.refresh()`

Comment: I suppose (my observations from debugging) that the copy events are somehow connected with checking changes of variables in angular library while $digest event. According to documentation $digest go through all bound variables and checks if the value has changed. And I suppose, if the variable is not changed, it creates new instance and copies the old value to the new instance, in this case whole array.